# How to get plane geometry associated with primitive 3d plane in unity3d

Tags: unity

I assume there should be a plane (struct) associated with a primitive 3d plane in unity3d, how to get that? 
Or if not associated, can we build plane struct object somehow using corner vertices of 3d plane. Can somebody help me how to get cornor vertices of 3d plane mesh.

Update:
What I am trying to achieve is to use Plane.Raycast on a 3d Plane, but I am not certain whether there is any plane geometry component associated with it, or Is there any way to build a plane geometry which should be going through all the corners of the 3d plane, so that I'll be able to use Plane.Raycast from the normal direction of 3d plane towards itself.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your question is about. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get each individual vertex from a `Mesh`? If you are trying to render a specific shape, it would be better to export a 3D mesh from another software and import it to Unity.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to use Plane.Raycast on a 3d Plane, but I am not certain whether there is any plane geometry component associated with it, or I build a plane geometry which should be going through all the corners of the 3d plane, so that I'll be able to use Plane.Raycast from the normal direction of the 3d plane.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to mention that you want to use it for raycasting. It could help someone to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Sure, will do that, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Do you want to raycast against the infinite theoretical plane given by the point and normal? Or against the actual extents of the plane mesh? If the latter, you'll want Physics.Raycast or Collider.Raycast instead.

Comment: theoretical plane as my requirement is however full fulling with this, then why do I use Physics.Raycast or Collider.Raycast, which requires colliders, which are not very good when we talk about performance.
I am using these planes just to get a hit point, I dont need any renderer or collider for these planes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the built-in Plane primitive, it's a plane normal to the local up direction, passing through the local origin. So you can write:

```
Plane plane = new Plane(
                 planeObject.transform.up,
                 planeObject.transform.position
              );
```

Comment: So if I compute all four corners of the 3d plane (I don't know how), they all will lie on this plane geometry that you have created above using object's up direction and  position?

Comment: If you're using the default plane primitive, its corners lie at `planeObject.transform.TransformPoint(±5, 0, ±5)`. You can see they're in the local plane y=0, and the plane given above is the world coordinate image of that plane.